# Why is my nested while-loop looping infinitely?

Tags: c++

I am having trouble getting this nested while-loop to function how I want it to.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

double time_to_ground(double);

int main() {
    std::cout.precision(4);
    bool go = 1;
    double height{};
    while (go) {
        std::cout << "Please enter the height of the building in meters.\n";
        std::cin >> height;
        while (height < 0) {
            std::cout << "\nPlease enter a positive number.\n";
            std::cin >> height;
        }
        double time = time_to_ground(height);
        std::cout << "It will take " << time << " seconds for the ball to reach the ground to reach the ground.\n";
        std::cout << "Go again?\n0) no\n1) yes\n";
        std::cin >> go;
        //This loop breaks the code
        while (!((go == 0) || (go == 1))) {
            std::cout << "Enter either:\n0) no\n1) yes\n";
            std::cin >> go;
        }   
    }
    return 0;
}

double time_to_ground(double height) {
    return sqrt(2 * height / 9.81);

}
```

The idea is simply just to make sure the user only inputs a 0 or 1. It works fine if I put a 0 or 1, However when I run the code and input say, a 6, I get stuck in an infinite loop!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't understand why this question got two down votes. It's (almost) a [mre], it concerns an interesting point of the standard library (one I had to look up to be certain), and it's while I'm sure it's been asked before somewhere, it is fairly original.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `go` as a `bool` but you are trying to read it as an integer.

Just change `bool go = 1;` to `int go = 1;`

Trying to read an integer input that is not `0` or `1` into a boolean variable fails and once `cin` has failed all input using `cin` will fail until you clear the error. That's why you get an infinite loop.

An alternative way of writing the loop is to check for the input error directly. You can keep the go variable as `bool` and write this

```
    while (!(std::cin >> go))
    {
        std::cin.clear(); // clear the cin error
        std::cout << "Enter either:\n0) no\n1) yes\n";
    }
```

This works because `std::cin >> go` will return false if the input fails. Notice that I clear the error once it has occurred.

Comment: @GenoC Yes, fixed.

Comment: I was mid-typing my answer when you put my alternate solution up. +1

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution to this would be to keep `bool go = 1;` and then replace:

```
while (!((go == 0) || (go == 1))) {
            std::cout << "Enter either:\n0) no\n1) yes\n";
            std::cin >> go;
        }
```

with:

```
while (std::cin.fail())
        {
            std::cin.clear(); 
            std::cout << "Enter either:\n0) no\n1) yes\n";
            std::cin >> go;
        }
```

- `std::cin.fail()` returns *true* if the last `std::cin` input failed. But will return *false* otherwise.
- `std::cin.clear()` clears the error flag on `std::cin`.

Answer (score 0):

use int data type in your main function

```
int go = 1;
```

instead of bool

```
bool go = 1;
```

bool can not handle values other than 0,1
it will work.